# How to caculate this integral by Legendre Poly.

Tags: analysis, legendre-polynomials

How to caculate the integral

$$\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)\mathrm{P}_k'(x)\mathrm{P}_l'(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$

Where $\mathrm{P}_l(x)$ is the $l$ - oeder Legendre Poly.

Comment: Well, they are an orthogonal system... do you know these polynomials are solutions to  certain differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating by parts we obtain
$$
\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)P_k'(x)P_l'(x)\,dx = \left.(1-x^2)P_k'(x)P_l(x)\right|_{-1}^1
-\int_{-1}^1\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)P_k'(x)]P_l(x)\,dx. \tag{1} 
$$
The first term on the RHS of $(1)$ vanishes, and the second one can be simplified with the help of the differential equation satisfied by the Legendre polynomial $P_k(x)$,
$$
(1-x^2)P_k''(x)-2xP_k'(x)+k(k+1)P_k(x)=0 
$$
$$
\implies
\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)P_k'(x)]=-k(k+1)P_k(x). \tag{2}
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)P_k'(x)P_l'(x)\,dx &= k(k+1)\int_{-1}^1P_k(x)P_l(x)\,dx \\
&= \frac{2k(k+1)}{2k+1}\,\delta_{kl}, \tag{3}
\end{align}
where the last step follows from the normalization of the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality_and_completeness).

Comment: Thank you very much, But the eq(2) can be obtained by the Legendre equation 
 $\dfrac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)P_k'(x)]+k(k+1)P_k(x)=0$ beacuse Legendre Poly. is the solution of the Legendre eq.
Thanks again!